# How to read methods with in the apex class (content) and retrieve objects used with in the methids

Tags: apex, developer

I want to retrieve all methods used in a apex class and then find objects used within that method and retrieve fields used within the method for the object

Appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you have tried so far (adding some sample code of what you have tried up until this point would help) or some further explanation on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called introspection. Unfortunately, Apex doesn't provide you with the level of introspection that you're looking for. In fact, I don't know of any programming language that does.

Salesforce does, however, provide some detailed information through the web interface. If you go to

> Setup => Develop (menu on left side, under `App Setup`) => Apex Classes

and choose a specific class, one of the buttons on the top of the page will be `Show Dependencies`. The `Object Operational Scope` contains what you're looking for. You can dive into the individual sObjects to see which specific fields on that sObject are used in your class.

It also shows you which Apex classes and triggers that your class depends on (both classes in the inheritance hierarchy, and classes that are instantiated inside of the class you're inspecting)

There might be a way to get at this information via the metadata API, but I don't use the metadata API enough to know for sure.

Your other options here involve manual documentation.

[ApexDoc might be able to help you](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/ApexDoc).

You could also create and maintain a static `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>` for each class. Method name being the key of the outer map, sObject/Class name being the key of the inner map, and the `List<String>` to track fields used (or methods called/attributes used).

Comment: Of course these approaches may not access fields referenced by FieldSet or String (`a.get('Field__c')`) or dynamic SOQL.